# Chrome Export Bookmarks HTML missing folders

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, bookmarks

When i initiate the export bookmarks from bookmarks manager as an HTML file and save it, it works fine.

But,

When i import the HTML file in Firefox, i am missing folders from the chrome bookmarks which were **included** in the html file, (verified the list of bookmarks in NotePad++)  but did not show up in the list of bookmarks in FireFox.

So basically the HTML file includes 12 folders, only 4 folders are showing in FireFox.

Why? what is missing?

Comment: Could you post the HTML file with only folders here? It will be better if these folders contains one bookmark. BTW, there is a function called **import data from another browser** in FF. You can use that function to have a try, the bookmarks imported are under folder *From Google Chrome*.

Comment: #ynjxsjmh

Thanks for getting back to me.

I am not too sure how can i attach or post the HTML file here.

Comment: You could paste it into https://pastebin.com/ with time of expiry or just edit the question and paste it there. As a reminder, if your bookmarks are privacy related, you can replace those with some common sites when you post here. But remember to keep the original folder structure.

Comment: "BTW, there is a function called import data from another browser in FF. You can use that function to have a try, the bookmarks imported are under folder From Google Chrome."

With reference to the aforementioned that you included in your first reply,  I tried it first, the result was blank folder.   Tried it more than once, still blank folder.

Comment: I did paste the HTML content, only 179 lines though, i had to minimize the lines.
Original file in Notepad++ is 3211 lines.

"https://pastebin.com/ScEF5C8b"

Comment: This is how your posted html file looks like after I import them to my firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Gl3.png. It's the same with web browser preview. Is this what you want? Could you offer your FF and Google Chrome version? There is a **New Profile Test** in https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1275941. Will you get the same problem on new profile?

Comment: That image:  "i.stack.imgur.com/01Gl3.png" looks like a messed up import.   This is not how it is in Chrome nor this is what i intended for it.

FF version = 76.0.1 (64-bit)
Chrome version =  81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)

And i think i figured out why it got messed up.
while saving the exported file from Chrome, i rename it.   Now i tried again without renaming the file.  All Bookmarks got imported.

However, the auto import, yields an EMPTY Chrome Folder still.

Comment: Though I have no idea why renaming exported bookmarks will cause this error, congratulations on solving it. The only assumption I could make about the EMPTY Google Chrome Folder is that there still exists chrome process. If not, I can't help anymore. If you'd like to figure it out, you could come to https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/firefox or [https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/](r/firefox) for more help.